# hide/show a part of events in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm building a calendar-based web app with fullcalendar, which is for college students to use. There are some categories I've defined. e.g, sport, art, mind, etc... every event in the fullcalendar would be assigned to a category.

What i want to do is: there're some checkboxes corresponding categories on the top of the calendar, and the user can check or uncheck some checkboxed to hide/show the related events

how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to put appropriate classes on each event by setting the 'className' property on the  event objects you're sending to the calendar and use jquery to hide those events (e.g. $(.myClassName).hide()) when they check the checkboxes.  The trouble is the events would vanish leaving a gap where they were which might not be what you want.

A better way would be to add a filter function to the events option when you first call fullCalendar like this:

```
fullCalendar({
...
events: {
  url: ....,
  success: function(events) {
    $.map(events, function (e) {
      if (userHasFilteredOut(e))
        return null;
      else
        return e;
    });
  },
...
});
```

This will filter out the events before they are displayed.  The function userHasFilteredOut returns true if the event object passed in is of a class the user's checkbox values indicate is filtered out.  When the user checks or unchecks a checkbox, you will need to refetch all the events from the server.  You need to do this:

```
$('#mycal').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

Comment: this works but it should be: success: function(events) { events = $.map(events, function (e) { ... }); return (events);

Comment: What if there are drag'n'drop constraints ? I need to hide the events, but I need the drag'n'drop to still respect the overlapping policies. Is there a way to do that ?